# Displaying Divs that are included via PHP

Tags: css

I have my index broken into a few divs. Within those divs I use PHP to include content to fill those divs. A quick example of how it looks:

```
<div class="top">
   <?php include xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ?>
</div>

<div class="body">
   <?php include yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy ?>
</div>
```

My issue/question is when I resize my window to make it smaller, the top div does not push the body div down when the top div resizes(the content within is auto height).

The CSS for .top and .body have been everything I could think of,inline, block, relative, absolute, fixed, etc... But I cannot get one to influence the other in any way. Is this manageable or not possible due to the fact they use PHP includes?

The stylesheets are all called at the beginning via CSS and changes do show, so I know the sytem I have set up is working, it is a matter of getting the divs to interact correctly when resized.

Comment: you have to include your CSS, and maybe also the contents (HTML, CSS) of those included DIVs

Comment: This not a PHP question! Resizing the window works on the **client** side.

Comment: If you have some absolute positioned elements in `.top`, those will not be in regular content flow, which means they will not take up room in `.top` and consequently `.body` will not be pushed lower down the page.  As posted, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: @MarcAudet, thank you. I am fairly new to this and had absolute items within the div from before i used php to include everything. thank you for your input! I will rewrite it and see how it works :)